# Linux + Windows on kvm-switch. Windows works, Linux does not

Tags: linux, display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, kvm-switch

I have a dual-port, dual-dvi kvm ( dual dvi monitors for 2 computers ). One port is for Windows 7/64, the other port is Linux Mint/64.

Windows almost always works, meaning I get hot, dual-screen action. The linux machine very seldom works, meaning neither monitor will show anything. Sometimes, if I reboot the Linux box ( once or twice or thrice ) it too will work. Yet most of the I can't get anthing to show on my monitors.

I've tried switching KVMs ( I have a LinksKey LDV-DM702AUSK and a StarTech SV231DVIDDU ), switching the KVM port each machine uses, and switching the DVI cables that each machine uses. In all cases, I cannot get the linux box to display, and the Windows box does work.

My theory, at this point, is that there is perhaps some linux video config thingy I could do, or the video card itself is possibly the problem. I've yet to try switching video cards between the two machines and see what happens.

Anyway, any thoughts on what my problem is, or even what other tests I could run to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm answering my own question, but I figured it out, and it was one of my theories mentioned in the original post ... I replaced the nVidia-based video card with a relative cheapy AMD-based card ( which supports dual dvi at 1900 x 1280 ) and it comes up absolutely every single time.  I'm having absolutely no problems with my KVM at all.